# Use feature as module?

Tags: hooks, features

Does anyone have experience with using a feature as a module?
The usage I am talking about is strictly placing hooks inside the .module file.
Can that trigger any sort of bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can use a feature like a "normal" module.

Feature use .module file only for include a file, so after this include you could add your custom code.
And obviously you can add more files, directories, etc.

It's a great way to avoid to create too many modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a feature as a "normal" module without any problems. I've found it very convenient.